# Shell Script write parameters using for

Tags: shell, for-loop, parameters, sh

```
for (( i=1; i<=$#; i++ ))
do
    echo "$($i)"    <---this is not correct, how should i fix that?
done
```

I would like to print all of the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for arg; do
    echo "$arg";
done
```

or

```
for ((i=0; i<=${#@}; i++ )); do
    echo "${!i}"
done
```

or

```
for arg in "$@"; do
    echo "$arg";
done
```